# Simple wireless interface

Tags: microcontroller, wireless

I need to get some data from remote limit switch. The distance is 1000m ( clear line of site) or less. I can think of 2 or 3 messages to transmit: "switch closed", "switch open" and (optionaly) "battery low". Nothing will be sent in return. There will be (or at least, can be) a uC close to the switch. I know modules like NRF24L01+PA+LNA or HC-12 will probably do the trick, but I wonder if there is a simpler solution, something like RFM110, but powerful enough for such distance? Maybe there is some module that can transmit some data stored in its EEPROM when one of its GPIO is pulled high/low.

UPD: A switch when closed is sending some specific code every 100ms, it is ok if the main uC will get the message at second or even third attempt.

Comment: A lot depends on what is in the 1000' between the radios.  Is there clear line of site, foliage, building walls?

Comment: It even more depends on your acceptable error rate. Not having a return channel is bad for reliability, so this might increase cost and/or complexity, under high-reliability constraints.

Comment: Also, define with hard numbers a maximum latency, aside from hard numbers for error probabilities limits

Comment: Take a look at LORA, probably a better solution than NRF24L01 for low bandwidth, long range communication.